# pandas data frame to excel version change ( Index Name on separate row from column )

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

Recently, I have been using  Anaconda 2.3.0, which has pandas version 0.16.2 and xlsxwriter version 0.7.3. I just reinstalled a newer Anaconda version, which is  Anaconda2-4.0.0 which has pandas version of pandas version of 0.18.0 and xlsxwriter 0.8.4. Suddenly, many of the programs, that generate excel files with native excel charts that I have written in the past suddenly stopped working. Here is why:

For a simple dataframe with 3 columns named A,B,C:

With previous Version of pandas and xlsxwriter,  df.to_excel() would generate an excel file like this,

[image]

With the new pandas and xlsxwriter version, here is what I get.

[image]

The difference is quite subtle. But, because one row difference, the subsequent steps of the program that relies on the excel file stopped working.

I know that I can manipulate the dataframe such that the output in excel file is going to look like the previous case, namely by inserting an NaN row and give the index name as "Path". But, I don't want to do that since my current program is quite complicated and there are over 100 dataframes that are being put in excel file on various sheets. Another reason is I also want the code to be backward compatible, if possible i.e the program will still work if I run the code with Anaconda version  2.3.0.

Is there a one line solution to use df.to_excel("file_name.xlsx") such that it would generate an excel file with dataframe has the index name separate row with columns.

Comment: After testing a bit I can see that the problem goes both ways, i.e. when I try to read a file formatted as seen in the first image, I get a row of NaNs. Am I correct to presume that you need a 2-way solution (reading and writing)? If so, wouldn't it be better to go through all of your files just once and rewrite them in this new format?

Comment: At this point, I only need a solution for writing.  It is not a good excuse. But, given the size of my program, it is quite a lot of work to rewrite and test it. More importantly, I am not sure if and when they will revert to  the old format. For me, the old format makes a lot of sense. 

The new format does not allow you to differentiate between the index name and the column. This can be problematic.